# How to Determine the Number of Followers on Facebook php

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Facebook enables you to have both friends and followers on the network. Friendship is a two-way relationship -- you can see the updates of your friends, and they can see yours (depending on the privacy settings configured for each post). If you follow someone, this is a one-way relationship: You can see the user's public updates, but that individual doesn't see yours.

i have my own id where  new people add me as friend but i on follow option. so new user follow me.is there any way i can get followed number in php.

Comment: i tried this 'https://graph.facebook.com/USER-ID/subscribers?access_token=TOKEN-NR'

Comment: i am still confuse is it possible or not.............

Comment: valid reason ....................

Comment: ask facebook about the reason why it´s not possible. as you can see in the docs, there is no field or endpoint for this.

Comment: man this is reason that you define ...why you not put this as answer ...thanks for clear my query

Answer (score 0):

very thank for **luschn** helping me

well i found its solution it was very easy hence Facebook doc / FQl not supported this function but getting number of followers is very easy 
just 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/follow-button
my recommendation visit above line mention code is for sample only
**Your Plugin Code**

1. Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening  tag.

> (function(d, s, id) {   var js, fjs =
>   d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;   js
>   = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
>   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script',
>   'facebook-jssdk'));

2. Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

> *your
>   profile id place here(you can view this click on your profile copy
>   url)* "
>
> > data-layout="standard" data-show-faces="true">